# LoadImageFromUrl IBitmap to ImageSource

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, akavache

I am using the code below the Akavache to cache images.

Return is an IBitmap, how can I convert this IBitmap to an ImageSource?

```
var url = "https://ashdbhjas/image.png";
ImageSource imageSrc = await BlobCache.LocalMachine.LoadImageFromUrl(url); // ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var url = "https://ashdbhjas/image.png";
var img = await BlobCache.LocalMachine.LoadImageFromUrl(url); 

MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();

await img.Save(CompressedBitmapFormat.Jpeg, 1.0f, imageStream);

stream.Position = 0;
var imageSrc = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageStream);
```

Basically you are saving the IBitmap into a MemoryStream then using this to create your ImageSource object of your Image.

Hope this helps!